# Attack button in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, button, sprite-kit

I'm slightly new to Xcode and have been making a 2d game for my class. I have been having issues with buttons for a while now. I had just got a solution to why my jump button was not functioning, but I also have an attack button.

I have the code set up for the button to be on screen and to do its image change when pressed. However, I do not know what code to put in to change the player image to the jump animation. I also have no clue how to get collisions set up for it and the enemy so the attack animation will hit.

So my question is, how can I have the button start the jump animation and also how can I set up the collisions to destroy the enemy when hit?

This is my code so far:

```
override func sceneDidLoad() {
    //Setup start button
    jumpButton = SKSpriteNode(texture: jumpButtonTexture)
    jumpButton.position = CGPoint(x: 1850, y: 130)
    jumpButton.size = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)
    jumpButton.zPosition = 20

    addChild(jumpButton)

    //Setup start button
    attackButton = SKSpriteNode(texture: attackButtonTexture)
    attackButton.position = CGPoint(x: 1550, y: 130)
    attackButton.size = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)
    attackButton.zPosition = 20

    addChild(attackButton)
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        if selectedButton != nil {
            handleJumpButtonHover(isHovering: false)
            handleAttackButtonHover(isHovering: false)
        }

        if jumpButton.contains(touch.location(in: self)) {
            selectedButton = jumpButton
            handleJumpButtonHover(isHovering: true)
        } else if attackButton.contains(touch.location(in: self)) {
            selectedButton = attackButton
            handleAttackButtonHover(isHovering: true)
        }
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        if selectedButton == jumpButton {
            handleJumpButtonHover(isHovering: false)

            if (jumpButton.contains(touch.location(in: self))) {
                handleJumpButtonClick()
            }
        } else if selectedButton == attackButton {
            handleAttackButtonHover(isHovering: false)

            if (attackButton.contains(touch.location(in: self))) {
                handleAttackButtonClick()
            }
        }
    }
    selectedButton = nil
    }

    func handleJumpButtonHover(isHovering : Bool) {
    if isHovering {
        jumpButton.texture = jumpButtonPressedTexture
    } else {
        jumpButton.texture = jumpButtonTexture
    }
}

func handleAttackButtonHover(isHovering : Bool) {
    if isHovering {
        attackButton.texture = attackButtonPressedTexture
    } else {
        attackButton.texture = attackButtonTexture
    }
}

func handleJumpButtonClick() {
    self.playerNode.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
    self.playerNode.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 20))
}

func handleAttackButtonClick() {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first half of your question is quite easy.  You just need to set the new texture of your player in that function then once that animation is complete, revert back to the original player animation.  So I would suggest creating those two animations at the class level and assigning a key to the default animation and use the completion handler of the attack action to set it back.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    let frame2 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Ttam2")
    let frame3 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Ttam3")
    let frame4 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Ttam4")

    let attackFrame1 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Ttam1_ATTACK")
    let attackFrame2 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Ttam2_ATTACK")

    var animation: SKAction!
    var attackAnination: SKAction!

    override func sceneDidLoad(){
       animation = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.animate(with: [playerTexture, frame2, frame3, frame4], timePerFrame: 0.2))

       attackAnimation = SKAction.animate(with: [attackFrame1,attackFrame2],timePerFrame: 0.2)

       playerNode.run(animation,withKey:"animate")
    }

    func handleAttackButtonClick(){
        playerNode.removeAction(forKey:"animate")
        playerNode.run(attackAnimation,completion:{
             self.playerNode.run(animation,withKey: "animate")
        })
    }
}
```

As for your second half regarding collisions, what you want to use is `contactTestBitmask`.  You add the SKPhysicsContactDelegate to your scene class and set the bitmasks of which nodes you want to register contacts on.  There many questions and answers regarding that aspect all over SO. No need to answer again I don't think.  Feel free to come back with a new question if you get hung up on it.

Comment: ooh ok, so i would state that the attackFrame1 and 2 are the image inside of the create player? and then have the code that animates it inside of the fun handle AttackButtonClick() correct?

Comment: attackFrame 1 and 2 are your SKTextures for the attack images.  Just like you did for the normal animation.  You're just running the animation action on the node in that function.

Comment: i seem to still be having problems with the animation. i have the animation for the character walking inside of the func createPlayer. i have the animation set as a let animation = SKAction.animate(with:). i may just be putting the attackFrame1 and attackFrame2 in the wrong place. also, when putting the animation = SKAction.repeatForever in the sceneDidLoad() it comes up as an unresolved identifier

Answer (score 2):

I've writen a small 'starter' project that demonstrates in a  simple way (I hope) a lot of the concepts - just drop the code into a new project and run :

---

Here is a simple Sprite-Kit GameScene.swift. Create a new, empty SpriteKit project and replace the GameScene.swift with this. Then build and run.

Click on any of the objects on screen to give make them move. Check the logs and the comments to see which ones collide and which ones make contact.

```
//
//  GameScene.swift
//  bounceTest
//
//  Created by Stephen Ives on 05/04/2016.
//  Copyright (c) 2016 Stephen Ives. All rights reserved.
//

import SpriteKit



class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    let objectSize = 150
    let initialImpulse: UInt32 = 300  // Needs to be proportional to objectSize

    //Physics categories
    let purpleSquareCategory:   UInt32 = 1 << 0
    let redCircleCategory:      UInt32 = 1 << 1
    let blueSquareCategory:     UInt32 = 1 << 2
    let edgeCategory:           UInt32 = 1 << 31

    let purpleSquare = SKSpriteNode()
    let blueSquare = SKSpriteNode()
    let redCircle = SKSpriteNode()

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)

        //Create an boundary else everything will fly off-screen
        let edge = frame.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: 0)
        physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: edge)
        physicsBody?.isDynamic = false  //This won't move
        name = "Screen_edge"

        scene?.backgroundColor = SKColor.black

        //        Give our 3 objects their attributes

        blueSquare.color = SKColor.blue
        blueSquare.size = CGSize(width: objectSize, height: objectSize)
        blueSquare.name = "shape_blueSquare"
        blueSquare.position = CGPoint(x: size.width * -0.25, y: size.height * 0.2)

        let circleShape = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: CGFloat(objectSize))
        circleShape.fillColor = SKColor.red
        redCircle.texture = view.texture(from: circleShape)
        redCircle.size = CGSize(width: objectSize, height: objectSize)
        redCircle.name = "shape_redCircle"
        redCircle.position = CGPoint(x: size.width * 0.4, y: size.height * -0.4)

        purpleSquare.color = SKColor.purple
        purpleSquare.size = CGSize(width: objectSize, height: objectSize)
        purpleSquare.name = "shape_purpleSquare"
        purpleSquare.position = CGPoint(x: size.width * -0.35, y: size.height * 0.4)

        addChild(blueSquare)
        addChild(redCircle)
        addChild(purpleSquare)

        redCircle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: redCircle.size.width/2)
        blueSquare.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: blueSquare.frame.size)
        purpleSquare.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: purpleSquare.frame.size)

        setUpCollisions()

        checkPhysics()

    }


    func setUpCollisions() {

        //Assign our category bit masks to our physics bodies
        purpleSquare.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = purpleSquareCategory
        redCircle.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = redCircleCategory
        blueSquare.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = blueSquareCategory
        physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = edgeCategory  // This is the edge for the scene itself

        // Set up the collisions. By default, everything collides with everything.

        redCircle.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask &= ~purpleSquareCategory  // Circle doesn't collide with purple square
        purpleSquare.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0   // purpleSquare collides with nothing
        //        purpleSquare.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask |= (redCircleCategory | blueSquareCategory)  // Add collisions with red circle and blue square
        purpleSquare.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = (redCircleCategory)  // Add collisions with red circle
        blueSquare.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = (redCircleCategory)  // Add collisions with red circle


        // Set up the contact notifications. By default, nothing contacts anything.
        redCircle.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask |= purpleSquareCategory   // Notify when red circle and purple square contact
        blueSquare.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask |= redCircleCategory     // Notify when blue square and red circle contact

        // Make sure everything collides with the screen edge and make everything really 'bouncy'
        enumerateChildNodes(withName: "//shape*") { node, _ in
            node.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask |= self.edgeCategory  //Add edgeCategory to the collision bit mask
            node.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.9 // Nice and bouncy...
            node.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0.1 // Nice and bouncy...
        }

        //Lastly, set ourselves as the contact delegate
        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    }

    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        let contactMask = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask

        switch contactMask {
        case purpleSquareCategory | blueSquareCategory:
            print("Purple square and Blue square have touched")
        case redCircleCategory | blueSquareCategory:
            print("Red circle and Blue square have touched")
        case redCircleCategory | purpleSquareCategory:
            print("Red circle and purple Square have touched")
        default: print("Unknown contact detected")
        }
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        for touch in touches {
            let touchedNode = selectNodeForTouch(touch.location(in: self))

            if let node = touchedNode {
                node.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(initialImpulse)) - CGFloat(initialImpulse/2), dy: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(initialImpulse)) - CGFloat(initialImpulse/2)))
                node.physicsBody?.applyTorque(CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(20)) - CGFloat(10))
            }

        }
    }

    // Return the sprite where the user touched the screen
    func selectNodeForTouch(_ touchLocation: CGPoint) -> SKSpriteNode? {

        let touchedNode = self.atPoint(touchLocation)
        print("Touched node is \(touchedNode.name)")
        //        let touchedColor = getPixelColorAtPoint(touchLocation)
        //        print("Touched colour is \(touchedColor)")

        if touchedNode is SKSpriteNode {
            return (touchedNode as! SKSpriteNode)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    //MARK: - Analyse the collision/contact set up.
    func checkPhysics() {

        // Create an array of all the nodes with physicsBodies
        var physicsNodes = [SKNode]()

        //Get all physics bodies
        enumerateChildNodes(withName: "//.") { node, _ in
            if let _ = node.physicsBody {
                physicsNodes.append(node)
            } else {
                print("\(node.name) does not have a physics body so cannot collide or be involved in contacts.")
            }
        }

        //For each node, check it's category against every other node's collion and contctTest bit mask
        for node in physicsNodes {
            let category = node.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask
            // Identify the node by its category if the name is blank
            let name = node.name != nil ? node.name! : "Category \(category)"

            let collisionMask = node.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask
            let contactMask = node.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask

            // If all bits of the collisonmask set, just say it collides with everything.
            if collisionMask == UInt32.max {
                print("\(name) collides with everything")
            }

            for otherNode in physicsNodes {
            if (node.physicsBody?.dynamic == false) {
                print("This node \(name) is not dynamic")
            }
                if (node != otherNode) && (node.physicsBody?.isDynamic == true) {
                    let otherCategory = otherNode.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask
                    // Identify the node by its category if the name is blank
                    let otherName = otherNode.name != nil ? otherNode.name! : "Category \(otherCategory)"

                    // If the collisonmask and category match, they will collide
                    if ((collisionMask & otherCategory) != 0) && (collisionMask != UInt32.max) {
                        print("\(name) collides with \(otherName)")
                    }
                    // If the contactMAsk and category match, they will contact
                    if (contactMask & otherCategory) != 0 {print("\(name) notifies when contacting \(otherName)")}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```