# Swift // Sprite Kit: Category Bit Mask Limitations

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, collision-detection, limit

There's something that's always puzzled me about category bit masks, and I'm reaching a point where I'm going to need a greater understanding of them.  I understand how they work on a fundamental level.  Say I was making a dungeon crawler basic hack and slash capabilities.  I might use a collection of categories like these:

```
enum PhysicsCategory{
    static let none: UInt32 = 0
    static let playerCategory: UInt32 = 0b1
    static let enemyCategory: UInt32 = 0b10
    static let weaponCategory: UInt32 = 0b100
    static let collectibleCategory: UInt32 = 0b1000
    static let enemyProjectileCategory: UInt32 = 0b10000
}
```

This would probably suffice, I could test if I'm attacking the enemy, they're attacking me, etc.  That said, if I wanted to make a dungeon crawler with different enemy classes, different weapon types, and different enemy weaknesses and strengths, I feel like I'd run out of categories really fast:

```
enum PhysicsCategory{
    static let none: UInt32 = 0
    static let playerCategory: UInt32 = 0b1

    static let toxicWeaponCategory: UInt32 = 0b10
    static let iceWeaponCategory: UInt32 = 0b100
    static let explosiveWeaponCategory: UInt32 = 0b1000
    static let bluntWeaponCategory: UInt32 = 0b10000

    static let toxicEnemyCategory: UInt32 = 0b100000
    static let iceEnemyCategory: UInt32 = 0b1000000
    static let explosiveEnemyCategory: UInt32 = 0b10000000
}
```

I run out of options for enemies and haven't even gotten to things like collectibles, environmental objects, or bosses whose weaknesses and/or strengths make entirely new combinations.  How are these things typically accounted for?  What I'm trying to make demands more than what you see above and the books / guides I've read only explain this on a very basic level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`categoryBitmasks` are used mostly for contact and collision detection and to establish what has made contact with what at a high level i.e. player with collectible, enemy with weapon etc. I'd be tempted to subclass these nodes (enemies, collectibles, bosses) and make the 'effect' (toxic, ice, explosive) a property within the node so that after making contact with something, you can call the appropriate routine from `didBegin()` based upon the enemy 'effectType'.

All contacts go through `didBegin()` anyway, and you're going to have to test the toxic/ice/explosive category anyway to work out how to handle the contact, so changing this logic to test a property within the node contacted won't actually add much (if any) code to your program.

Edit: You could code your `didBegin()` like this:

```
      func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
         print("didBeginContact entered for \(String(describing: contact.bodyA.node!.name)) and \(String(describing: contact.bodyB.node!.name))")
    
         let contactMask = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask
    
         switch contactMask {
         case  playerCategory | enemyCategory:
            print("Playerand enemy have contacted.")
            let playerNode = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == playerCategory ? contact.bodyA.node : contact.bodyB.node
            let enemyNode = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == enemyCategory ? contact.bodyA.node : contact.bodyB.node
            let enemyType = enemyNode.contactType // toxic, ice, explosive
            processCollision(between: playerNode and: enemyNode ofType: enemyType)
    
         default:
            print("Some other contact occurred")
         }
```

Although you'd be more likely to extract the enemey's type in `processCollision()`

If you're not familiar with Swift's argument labels for parameters, the definition of `processCollision` could be:

```
func: processCollision(between node: SKSpriteNode, and node2: SkSpriteNode ofType type: string)
```

which allows you to refer to node1 and node2 in the function, but the calling syntax is more readable. Also `type` would probably be a enum of the available enemy types.

**Edit**

A few links to some SK guides you may (or may not) find useful:

My step-by-step guide for collisions and contacts:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51041474/1430420

And a guide to collision and contactTest bit masks:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40596890/1430420

Manipulating bit masks to turn individual collision and contacts off and on.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46495864/1430420

Small sample project with contacts, collision and touches
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43605825/1430420

Comment: Thanks for this Steve, I appreciate it.  For me the issue has always been what function / class to call, but subclassing appears to be the answer.  Oddly enough I can get my game scene to acknowledge a collision between the player and a subclassed enemy, but not a subclassed weapon and a subclassed enemy.  

Probably a dumb oversight, best to look again in the morning.

Comment: That sounds weird - I wrote a space Invaders game a while back and I'm sure all the main sprites (player, enemies and their missile and bombs) were all subclasses of SKSpriteNode. Maybe check all the necessary contact setup again.

Comment: Also if you subclass the enemies and the definition of the subclass contains the toxic/ice/explosive collision logic, then `processCollision` is the only call you have to making the main code neater and the logic in the subclass can handle all the differences.

Comment: The problem ended up being a liberal use of "isDynamic = false" on the physics bodies.    The book I'm using for reference uses that frequently and I saw the description indicated that property dictates whether a physics body can be moved by physics stimulation.  I didn't want that, so I followed suit.  Apparently it has an impact not just on what happens on collision, but collision detection as a whole.

Comment: @user3786661 Yep - I've seen `isDynamic` catch people out before. I don't know how good your SK knowledge is, but I've added some links to some answers of mine that others have said they find useful.

Comment: Thanks Steve, I'll check those out.  It might be most accurate to say that I'm acquainted with SK.  This is a project I started and stopped over the years - a little short of eight now, if I'm not mistaken.  I'm presently working on a transition from objective-C to swift.  Other matters end up taking a higher priority or catching my attention.  If only there more were hours in a given day ...